# Nusoap, server side (php) and client side ASP classic

Tags: php, web-services, asp-classic, nusoap

> I am trying to call a **web service**
>   (using **nusoap**),  which work well when
>   I call it with a **php client**. 
>   It returns a list of mail address.

(there are plenty of examples around on the web about php/php or php/asp.net, etc...)

> **but, I want now to be able to call this web
>   service with classic ASP**

I have found nothing so far, 
does anyone have successfully implemented such a web service combo: php(server)/asp classic (client)?
Or know how to do it?
If the answer is yes,
I'd love to hear how you did that!
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you calling referring to classic ASP as "client side"?

Comment: Well,
philfreo, if you know a little bit about webservices,
you are surely aware that there is one client calling the web service.
and here the client is written in ASP (classic <> .NET),
that's it.

Comment: If we were helpful, please award answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the [Microsoft SOAP Tookit 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c943c0dd-ceec-4088-9753-86f052ec8450&displaylang=en), but I don't recommend it  because, in my experience is a pain.

There is also [this article in CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/SOAP___Classic_ASP.aspx), but I never use it, so can't recommend.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo! I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem. This code is working for me

```
url = "http://dev_api/service.php"

SOAPParameters = ""
SOAPParameters = " <param1>text1</param1>"
SOAPParameters = SOAPParameters & " <param2>text2</param2>"
SOAPParameters = SOAPParameters & " <param3>text3</param3>"

SOAPRequest = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " <soap:Body>"
SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " <search>"
SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & SOAPParameters
SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " </search>"
SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " </soap:Body>"
SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " </soap:Envelope>"

Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
xmlhttp.open "POST", url, false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", LEN(SOAPRequest)
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://dev_api/service.php" 
xmlhttp.Send (SOAPRequest)
Response.Write xmlhttp.responseXML.xml
```